# Crashes and doesn't install Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community- setup detected an issue during the operation,

Tags: vs-community-edition

When mounting the vs_community.exe file it said "setup detected an issue during the operation, Please click below to check for a solution and help us to improve the setup experience" I have seen a similar error and the solution was reinstalling fonts because the installer uses WPF, but it didn't work for me.

```
 **ERROR**: [3CB4:3A9C][2021-12-20T21:10:03]i000: MUX:  P1 - vs_community
[3CB4:3A9C][2021-12-20T21:10:03]i000: MUX:  P2 - 14.0.25420.01.00
[3CB4:3A9C][2021-12-20T21:10:03]i000: MUX:  P3 - 14.0.25420
[3CB4:3A9C][2021-12-20T21:10:03]i000: MUX:  P4 - Install
[3CB4:3A9C][2021-12-20T21:10:03]i000: MUX:  P5 - 
[3CB4:3A9C][2021-12-20T21:10:03]i000: MUX:  P6 - Crash: Exception
[3CB4:3A9C][2021-12-20T21:10:03]i000: MUX:  P7 - 5f52d5c0
[3CB4:3A9C][2021-12-20T21:10:03]i000: MUX:  P8 - 931
[3CB4:3A9C][2021-12-20T21:10:03]i000: MUX:  P9 - 1e
[3CB4:3A9C][2021-12-20T21:10:03]i000: MUX:  Adding Install Log to Watson=C:\Users\Elijah\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_community_20211220210957.log
[3CB4:3A9C][2021-12-20T21:10:03]i000: MUX:  Adding Install Log to Watson=C:\Users\Elijah\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_community_20211220210957.sqm
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, run **vs_community.exe** in administrator mode and check if you have write permission to the `%ProgramData%\Package Cache` directory.

Comment: If the problem is not solved, please share the log details in the `C:\Users\Elijah\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_community_20211220210957.log` directory.

Comment: The suggested above didn't worked. The log can't be post here since its too long so i just uploaded it in GDrive. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GUTNC1qoPnaPOLTMbg0m5j_c-pC51LFm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should also share this issue by visiting the [microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode) repository on GitHub. The problem may be specific. Follow [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md) and create new topic.

Comment: Additionally, the error code you shared may be missing. Examine the sample VS Code error code by clicking [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9aa8cc68-bfd0-419a-a65a-17e8a5248788/unable-to-install-visual-studio?forum=vssetup). Return Code number is not your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my registry is affected so Ive gone to the settings and chose the "RESET THIS PC" option, and after a while. My OS Windows is now a fresh install and somehow it solved my problem in launching the installer of VS 2015.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).